# Remove arrays from rest api return

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.4

I use rest api on my project and I have a problem. My entity field :

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Config", mappedBy="test", cascade={"persist"})
 * @Serializer\Expose
 * @Serializer\Groups({"v2"})
 */
private $configurations;
....
public function __construct()
{
    $this->configurations = ArrayCollection();
}
```

In my return I have :

```
 "configurations": [
    {
        "id": 52,
        "name": null,
    }
],
```

But I want to remove the array and return just object configurations, like :

```
"configurations": {
    "id": 52,
    "name": null,
}
```

So the idea is to get only one item from configurations array and return. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Jms you can use events like [onPreSerialize](https://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/event_system) method. Than you should put your first element in a virtual property.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that.

Add a property and use [Accessor](https://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/annotations#accessor) annotation.

```
/**
 * @Serializer\Accessor(getter="getFirstConfiguration")
 */
private $firstConfiguration;

public function getFirstConfiguration()
{
    return $this->configurations->first();
}
```